# Error when run the test "Cannot find module "

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jestjs, react-testing-library

I am new to writing Unit tests and i am trying to write unit tests to my react application using `testing-library/react` and `jest`

Here is the test code "Home.test.js"

```
import React from 'react';
import {render, cleanup} from '@testing-library/react';
import '@testing-library/jest-dom/extend-expect';
import Home from "../src/Home";    

afterEach(cleanup);

describe("Tests for HomePage", function() {
    it("should render without throwing an error", function() {
        const { homePage } = render(<Home />);
        //check something here
    });
});
```

Here is my code in component "Home.js"

```
import * as React from "react";

import { Panel, Shell, Button } from "@myorg/core";
import { home_icon, new_icon } from "@myorg/icons";

function Home(props) {
    const openDialog = React.useCallback(() => {
        //do something
    });

    return (
        <Shell.Page breadcrumbs={[t("demo:Home")]}>
            <Panel style={{ height: "100%" }}>
                <h2>App Header</h2>
                <Button onClick={openDialog} variant="primary">
                    <img src={new_icon} width="20" />
                    {t("demo:New Asset")}
                </Button>
            </Panel>
        </Shell.Page>
    );
}
```

error I get when I run "npm run test"

```
Cannot find module '@myorg/icons' from 'Home.js'
```

Comment: did you run `npm i "@myorg/icons"`?

Comment: @Clarity yes I did run

Comment: For anyone else that is having this issue, `npm install` should be the first thing you do.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I believe you are trying to use the `tsconfig.json` options [`paths`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/module-resolution.html), which will be ignored by jest (or by other testing frameworks). You need to manually replicate all your paths definition in `jest.config.js` and manually keep them updated using the jest config option [`moduleNameMapper`](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/configuration#modulenamemapper-object-string-string) like this:

```
  moduleNameMapper: {
    // translate all your custom paths here, read the doc in the link above
    '^@finder/(.*)$': '<rootDir>/files-manipulation/$1',
    '^@metadata/(.*)$': '<rootDir>/folder-metadata/$1',
    '^@logger/(.*)$': '<rootDir>/logging/$1',
    // ...and so on
  },
```